# 401:Unauthorized Error when calling Sharepoint Lists Web Service from .NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to create Lists in Sharepoint site from my ASP.NET code using the webservice (http://test.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx).The code i use is as follows.I am sure i have enough access to that sharepoint site.

```
sharepoint.enhanced1.Lists wsLists = new SharePoint_Test.sharepoint.enhanced1.Lists();
        wsLists.PreAuthenticate = true;
        wsLists.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        wsLists.AddList("Test_Code", "testing", 103);
```

This Code gives me the error:-
**The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.**
 Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: It has got something do with authorization only. Cross check your credentials and access rights.

Comment: Well, i have access to the sharepoint site(full access) and i am able to create Lists manually from sharepoint.Not sure what other access is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Working now..
i was using somewhat wrong asmx URL.
the one i was using was http://test.sharepoint.com/Lists/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
but the correct URL Shud be
http://test.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx  (**NO /Lists/).
Strange thing is that both URL's open up in browser without any problem,but fail in code.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

try it with the default network credentials

```
wsLists.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: I have used the same exact thing thing..doesn't work, i used DefaultNetworkCredentials,still no luck. I am able to get the "getListCollection" method working but when now when i use the UpdateListItems("TEST", element); i get Microsoft.Sharepoint.SoapServer Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and finaly disable ASP.NET Impersonation for my Sharepoint site in IIS Manager.